# How to add text positioned between two lines of a h1 tag

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve this look in a clean way:

[image]

I can make it happen with adding a large `line-height` and then a negative `margin-top` to the textbox but I doubt that's the best solution.

Here's the code I have

```css
.container {
 background-image: url(https://houniqueconstruction.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/kam-idris-_HqHX3LBN18-unsplash-scaled.jpg);
    background-position: bottom left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height:600px;
}

.overlay {
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.small-flexbox {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  max-width:1200px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:-340px;
}


h1, p, a {color:white;}

h1 {
 text-align:center;
 display:block;
  padding-top:1em;
  line-height:3;
  font-size:80px;
  letter-spacing:5px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}


a {
  border:15px solid #f5e2c8;
  padding:10px 30px;
  text-transform:uppercase;

}

.first-word {
  letter-spacing:11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    <h1><span class="first-word">Complete</span><br> Remodeling</h1>
    <div class="small-flexbox">
      <p style="max-width:400px; margin-right:3em">With 30 years of experience and a track record of successful projects, we have the skills and expertise to remodel your house with precision, efficiency, and minimal stress for you.</p>
      <a>Get a Quote</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems fine to me

Comment: What you've done is probably the best approach from an accessibility point of view; certainly better than splitting the H1 content in two.    You might consider putting all your CSS in the css file instead of having some of it inline in the HTML, though, just for easier maintenance.